# The wsdl is throwing an error when trying to generate the stub(WebService Client) from it

Tags: web-services, wsdl

This is my wsdl:

```
definitions targetNamespace="http://sei.profile.employee.com/" name="SimpleEmployeeProfileService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://sei.profile.employee.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://sei.profile.employee.com/" schemaLocation="EmployeeProfile_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="getEmployeeDetails">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getEmployeeDetails"/>
    <part name="departmentId" element="tns:departmentId"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getEmployeeDetailsResponse">
    <part name="result" element="tns:getEmployeeDetailsResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="SimpleEmployeeProfileService">
    <operation name="getEmployeeDetails" parameterOrder="parameters departmentId">
      <input ns1:Action="http://sei.profile.employee.com/EmployeeProfile/getEmployeeDetailsRequest" message="tns:getEmployeeDetails" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"/>
      <output ns2:Action="http://sei.profile.employee.com/EmployeeProfile/getEmployeeDetailsResponse" message="tns:getEmployeeDetailsResponse" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="SimpleEmployeeProfileServicePortBinding" type="tns:SimpleEmployeeProfileService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="getEmployeeDetails">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="SimpleEmployeeProfileService">
    <port name="SimpleEmployeeProfileServicePort" binding="tns:SimpleEmployeeProfileServicePortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/SimpleEmployeeProfileService"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

This is the error:

```
the prefix "soap" for element "soap:binding" is not bound
```

I have checked the tags but I haven't found any mistakes so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to the definition tag "xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" and it resolved my issue......

I will still keep this question posted since it might help some other user.